# WPF: Submit text on textchange when using DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf

Xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Question:
How can I do to make the binded Name property updated after the changing of the text in TextBox ? I said "changing" here means the user types on a keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

If you don't specify it, the UpdateSourceTrigger option is set to LostFocus.

Answer (score 1):

you can use  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged with Binding.

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

this will trigger when you changing the value.